# How can I determine which preprocessor macros in foo.c originate in bar.h?

Tags: c, parsing, static-code-analysis

I have two C language files: `foo.c` and `bar.h` (and possibly many other files). I want a list of all preprocessor macros which are used in `foo.c` and defined in `bar.h`.

Alternatively, if that's too difficult, even a list of all preprocessor macros (but *not* any identifier, word or piece of text) which appear in both `foo.c` and `bar.h`.

How can I obtain that?

Comment: I don't think there's a general answer to this, answering that kind of question is hard which is one reason it's a good idea to name one's preprocessor symbols well (e.g. `BAR_BLAH()` to show that the `BLAH()` macro comes from `bar.h`). You can try removing the `#include "bar.h"` and see if you get undefined-reference errors.

Comment: @unwind: If I had control over the names I would probably not have this problem... it's not my own code.

Comment: Are gcc-specific techniques acceptable?

Comment: @rici: Sure. I mean, if someone suggested something that's not gcc-specific I'd accept that over the more specific one but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can piece this information together from the output of gcc's preprocessing options.

To get the list of macros actually used by a file, you can use the `-E -dU` options, which preprocesses the file and also includes `#define` commands at the first *use* of any macro. (It also produces `#undef` commands for undefined names tested with `#ifdef` or `#if defined(...)`.) (You must use the `-E` option -- only preprocess --  for `-dU` to be handled properly.)

Since `-dU` does not suppress the preprocessed output, you need to filter it by looking only at the `#define` directives. For some applications, you might also want to further filter it by looking only at the uses actually in the file in question, since the report includes uses of macros by included files as well. But in this case, the intersection with the macros actually defined in the header file is probably sufficient.

So to get a list of used macros in `file.c`:

```
gcc -E -dU file.c | grep -Eo '^#define [_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

(The grep `-Eo` removes the definition of the macro.)

You can approximate a list of macros actually defined in a header file using a slightly more generous `grep` invocation, something like this:

```
grep -Eo '^\s*#\s*define\s+[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*' header.h
```

That will pick up macros defined in conditional sections even if the conditional fails, and it will pick up lines in comments which look like `#define` directives. Usually, neither of those will cause many problems.

You could use gcc's `-E -dM` or `-E -dD` options to get a list of all defines in a header, but both of those will also insert the macros defined by headers included by the header. (`-dM` also includes the predefined macros.) So you would really need to do some more work to focus on the macros actually defined by the header file, unless you are interested in all the macros defined as a result of including the header file.

Then you just need to find the intersection of the two lists. One way is to exract the macro names (`awk '{print $2}'`), `sort -u` both lists independently and then merge them, and finally pass them both through `uniq -d` to only look at the entries in both lists. (Both the following define the shell function `used_and_defined` which you would invoke `used_and_defined foo.c bar.h`)

```
used() {
  gcc -E -dU "$1" |
  grep -Eo '^#define [_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*' |
  cut -f2 -d' ' |
  sort -u
}

defined() {
  grep -Eo '^\s*#\s*define\s+[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*' "$1" |
  awk '{ print $2 }' |
  sort -u
}

used_and_defined() {
  cat <(used "$1") <(defined "$2") | sort | uniq -d
}
```

Or you could do the whole operation with `awk`

```
used_and_defined() {
  awk '/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define/ {
         gsub(/[ (].*/, "", $2);
         if (NR == FNR) ++macros[$2];
         else if (macros[$2]) print $2;
       }' \
       <(grep -Eo '^\s*#\s*define\s+[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*' "$2") \
       <(gcc -E -dU "$1")
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to remind readers what the meaning of `-E` and `-dU`? Also, your approximation is what I did so far - some regexp'ing on both files , then clean the line, sort and uniq to get approximate lists of macros names - then getting the difference using some uniq -c hackery

Comment: @einpoklum: Ok, added a brief description of the option and not very tested shell scripts.

Comment: The second awk script - why does it make sense to concatenate both files on the standard input (Assuming that's what you're doing there)?

Comment: @einpoklum: that is almost what it does. The two streams are both inputs, and I use the `NR == FNR` test to distinguish. It's an awk pattern: it lets you leverage the awk reader loop. In a different language I would have written two separate loops, probably using `popen` or equivalent .

Comment: @einpoklum: `<( command )` is *process substitution*. It is not a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy (admittedly cumbersome) could be:

foreach macro identifier *SOME_MACRO* in `bar.h`, run

```
gcc -E -DSOME_MACRO=recognizable_value foo.c | grep recognizable_value
```

i.e. preprocess the source and detect if an expansion happened. Note that this does not work for macros only used in `#if` directives and such.

Answer (score 0):

A `gcc`-specific (but `clang` has the same option with the same semantics) is to use `-dD` in addition to `-E`:

```
gcc -E -dD -o foo.i [other options] foo.c
```

will keep `#define` lines in the output, together with `# nnn "/path/to/file.h"` directives, so that you should be able to tell which macro belongs to which file. If you want to extract the macros that come from `bar.h`, Depending on the number of macros you expect to find in `bar.h`, the search command of your favorite editor might be sufficient, or a small awk/perl/python/... script would help.